# How to compare strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comparison

I have problem with comparing strings in JavaScript.

```
myMAV.on("PARAM_VALUE", function(message, fields) {
     var param = String(fields.param_id);
     console.log(param); //display "FLTMODE1"
     if(param.localeCompare("FLTMODE1") == 0){
          //..this code doesnt work  
     }else if(param.toUpperCase().localeCompare("FLTMODE1") == 0){
          //..this code doesnt work  
     }else if(param == "FLTMODE1"){
          //..this code doesnt work too
     }
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `param` is probably not exactly what you think it is. Could it contain leading or trailing spaces, newlines, etc.?

Comment: check it 
http://jsfiddle.net/grsbccug/

Comment: there was a null char on the end, that helped: var param = String(fields.param_id.split('\u0000')[0]); thnx!

Answer (score 0):

to remove the null char from the end:

```
var param = String(fields.param_id.split('\u0000')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is code for any two find if any two string is identical or not if any of the permutations of string 1 is equal to the string 2.

```
function main(str1 ,str2) {
    var magic = [ str1 , str2];
    var count=0;
    for(let k=0; k<magic[0].length; k++){
          if( magic[1].includes(magic[0][k])){
                  count++;        
          }else{
               console.log('NO')
          }
         if(count==magic[0].length){
              console.log('YES')
         }
    }
}
```